# Angular4 and Azure AD: impossible to catch data from the API : 401 Unauthorized

Tags: angular, azure, http, azure-active-directory

I have a problem building my Angular4/Angular2 app and Azure AD auth.

First of all I use ADAL-Angular4 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular4) and the angular server is running locally. 
On Azure, I've got a web app with API that I would like to secure.
So I created a Active directory App, and linked it with the web App (https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/381684Capturedcran20170719094203.png).

The first Auth works well (to access the web App).
But when it comes to call API ( which are restricted to Authenticated Users only), i got the following response everytime

```
401 error : Unauthorized
```

Seems like I can't access to the ressources because I don't have the granted access. but my account is an admin on all the apps, I have all access everywhere on Azure.

I was thinking that ADAL doesn't catch all the request but even when I put

```
let head = new Headers({Authorization: 'Bearer '+this.service.userInfo.token})
head.append( 'Host' , 'xxx.azurewebsites.net' )
return this._http.get('https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/getColumnsName/'{headers: head})
```

On my request service, it won't work, i get the same error...

Here is my Adal config placed on my app.component

```
const config = {
  tenant: 'XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com',
  clientId: 'XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX' //authApp ID
}                                   

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { 
     constructor(private service: Adal4Service) {      // <-- ADD
    this.service.init(config);                      // <-- ADD
  }                              
}
```

### edit :

When I authenticate I get those parameters (some have been hidden and the token has been cut for safety reasons)

```
[Log] username toto@hotmail.fr (main.bundle.js, line 2436)
[Log] authenticated: true (main.bundle.js, line 2437)
[Log] name: toto (main.bundle.js, line 2438)
[Log] token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Il
```

And the response send by the server is this one (comes from azure logs) :

```
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<h3>HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized</h3> 
<h4>You do not have permission to view this directory or page.</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.</li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
<div id="details-left"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;iisnode</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;iisnode</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr> 

</table> 
</div> 
<div id="details-right"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://XXXXX:80/app.js</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aad</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;toto@hotmail.fr</td></tr> 

</table> 
<div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
This is the generic Access Denied error returned by IIS. Typically, there is a substatus code associated with this error that describes why the server denied the request. Check the IIS Log file to determine whether a substatus code is associated with this failure. 
<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=401,0,0x00000000,9200">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 
<p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p> 


</fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

### edit2 :

I use azure "easy API" with the get/post/request permissions set to 'Authenticated Users Only'

Comment: Missing a comma or is that a typo? There should be one after your URL because headers is a parameter to `http.get()`. We have a similar solution in place and working, the only other difference (with the limited view of your code) is that we append an `'Accept'` header as well with value of `'application/json'`.

Comment: The comma is present in my code, stack editor take it away idk why. Even when I add your line, it respond my unauthorised. Maybe i miss configure my azure add and web app ? @DSN

Comment: There should be a longer message along with the `401 error`. Can you share that message? Would you also be able to share the contents of your access token (removing any sensitive data)?

Comment: I've add it @ShawnTabrizi

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have configured authentication on your web API via IIS or some other type of mechanism (not sure which).  But in general, if you want to validate tokens issued by Azure AD & acquired by the ADAL library, you can use the `WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationMiddleware` in your ASP.NET apps to process tokens & authenticate incoming calls.  [Here's a basic sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp/blob/master/TodoSPA/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L14-L22) which shows how to use this middleware.  Alternatively, you could also use the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` library to validate tokens from Azure AD, as is done in [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs#L137).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I forget to says that I'm using directly Azure Easy API, so that I do not have ( normally) to do this kind of stuff (I've made an edit) @dstrockis

Comment: @Antoine Based on the figure, you protect the web API however allowed the anonymous requests. It seems that you also protect the web API in the project, would you mind checking it and sharing the code?